# How can i add images from webpage in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**Im trying to add logo of coloplast in my project** URL(`https://www.coloplast.com/Global/1_Corporate_website/Press/Pics/CPlogo_Gray_RGB_300.png`).

**And i always got this error **

> Server Error
> Error: Invalid src prop (https://www.coloplast.com/Global/1_Corporate_website/Press/Pics/CPlogo_Gray_RGB_300.png) on `next/image`, hostname "www.coloplast.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
> See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

## I tryed diferents website such as google images, and stil doesn't work...

```
  protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'www.coloplast.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/account123/**',
```

```
  images: {
      domains: ["www.coloplast.com"] and ["coloplast.com"]
  }
```

**And after each method i restarted my project from console.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on NextJS official docs about [next/image remote pattern](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#remote-patterns), "To protect your application from malicious users, configuration is required in order to use external images. This ensures that only external images from your account can be served from the Next.js Image Optimization API."

So in your case, you have to add this code between curly braces of your nextConfig variable in next.config.js file:

```
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        {
          protocol: 'https',
          hostname: 'www.coloplast.com',
        },
      ],
    },
```

Comment: ok, here is my code ```/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'www.coloplast.com',
      },
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig;```

Comment: but still got error

Comment: ```      <Link href="/catalog">
                <Image
                  src="https://www.coloplast.com/Global/1_Corporate_website/Press/Pics/CPlogo_Gray_RGB_300.png"
                  alt="логотип бренда"
                  width={120}
                  height={20}
                />
              </Link>```

Comment: Did you add "https://www." at the beginning of your Image src or I can't see that here?

Comment: I'm using next 13.1.0 and I tried and managed to display the logo with the mentioned URL using next/image and the settings I mentioned earlier without any problems.

Comment: yes, full adress it - https://www.coloplast.com/Global/1_Corporate_website/Press/Pics/CPlogo_Gray_RGB_300.png

Comment: Please tell me, I have updated next.js 12.3.4. and prescribe remotePatterns. But when building, I get into images (the "url" parameter is not allowed). Have you ever encountered such a thing ? I described the problem in more detail in the topics below: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50028 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76181016/what-wrong-next-js-image-dont-work-on-server